# JavaScript get data attributes from nodeList?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to webscrape data attributes.

```
<div class="class1">
    <div class="class2">
        <div data-example="hi">

        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
<div class="class1">
    <div class="class2">
        <div data-example="hi">

        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll('.class1 .class2');
console.log(list[list.length - 1]);
```

This returns raw HTML in the console, which I can't use to access the data-attribute values. Unfortunately, I cannot change the format of the HTML and I'm only interested in getting `data-example` when it's from `.class1 .class2`.

I'm getting HTML when I access any of the results from `querySelectorAll`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll('.class1 .class2 div[data-example]');
console.log(list[list.length - 1].getAttribute('data-example'));
```

http://jsbin.com/luyovumu/1/

Comment: hm why does it convert to HTML when I set list[list.length-1] to a variable? Is it because it loses the prototype needed to use `getAttribute`?

Comment: It's just a way for the console to display it. It's still a markup node, but it draws out the node that it found in full markup

Comment: note - i change selector. In your case there are no data-attribute ( and html is just a string view of element to print for console )

Comment: The nodes you selected are still able to be grabbed as if they were objects. Play around in the Chrome console a little. It has intellisense on what calls and variables can be referenced off of objects